# Jquery Validation Plugin digits that aren't required not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm trying to setup a "digit" field using the [jQuery Validation plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/digits-method/)

The problem is I don't want the digit field to be required, I just want to validate it as digits only, if someone does enter anything into it.

Here is my code, if I remove the "required: true," part, the field no longer throws up an error if I enter text into it and the form gets passed.

```
$('.js-validate-form').validate({
  rules: {
      phoneNumber: {
      digits: true
    }
  }
});
```

And my HTML

```
<input type="number" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="Phone (include area code)" value=""/>
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This only seems to be a problem with `input type="number"` fields.  It also only works as long as your field `name` matches your rule declaration, in this case, `phoneNumber`...

```
<input type="text" name="phoneNumber" id="phone" placeholder="Phone (include area code)" value=""/>
```

**DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/L4crh/**

---

However, there are various phone number rules you can use that are already included in this plugin as part of [the `additional-methods.js` file](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/additional-methods.js)

**DEMO 2:  http://jsfiddle.net/L4crh/1/**

---

**EDIT**:

The `type="number"` bug has reportedly been resolved as of jQuery Validate version 1.13.

https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/releases/tag/1.13.0

Comment: That works perfectly, thanks heaps for your help Sparky! I didn't know that "additional methods" file existed either, will be sure to use that. Thanks again!